# Frames get from front camera of Android are stretch to the screen

Tags: android

I'm new in Android programming. I've already program an application that makes the phone which has front camera likes a mirror. I use front camera to do that, but a problem is that when I look at myself via the screen, my head is stretched (it means my head is lengthen) and it looks so funny. Could anyone help me fix this, I appreciate that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you rendering the image captured by the camera? You should post the relevant code too.